# Declaration and definition mismatch

Tags: c++, templates, declaration, definition, mismatch

A declaration and definition mismatch in my template class (everything irrelevant has been cut out):

```
template <typename LanguageMap>
class WidgetLanguageManager
{
    public:
        enum class Language { DE, ENG, PL };
    protected:
        Language language;
        //Some protected fields
    public:
        explicit WidgetLanguageManager(const Language& language);
        explicit WidgetLanguageManager(const QString& language);
        Language ToLanguage(const QString& language);
    protected:
        //some protected methods
};


template <typename LanguageMap>
Language WidgetLanguageManager<LanguageMap>::ToLanguage(const QString& language) // this cannot be matched with a declaration
{
    for (QChar& c: language)
    {
        c = c.toLower();
    }

    switch (language)
    {
        case "german": return Language::DE;
        case "english": return Language::ENG;
        case "polish": return Language::PL;
    }
    throw RuntimeError("Wrong language paremeter.");
}
```

Please help because I cannot see any reason behind that.

Comment: For such questions, always provide the error message(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following would work:

```cpp
template <typename LanguageMap>
typename WidgetLanguageManager<LanguageMap>::Language WidgetLanguageManager<LanguageMap>::ToLanguage(const QString& language)
// ^^^^^ 'typename' keyword needed because 'Language' is dependent name
```

Since `enum class Language` is part of `WidgetLanguageManager` template class, you need to precede it with the scope operator.

Comment: This helped:
template <typename LanguageMap>
typename WidgetLanguageManager<LanguageMap>::Language WidgetLanguageManager<LanguageMap>::ToLanguage(const QString& language)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to extra `typename`, you might use trailing return type:

```
template <typename LanguageMap>
auto WidgetLanguageManager<LanguageMap>::ToLanguage(const QString& language)
-> Language
{
/*..*/
}
```